# I have two different permissions on a list on SharePoint with Full Control and Read Only. Which permission will be my main permission on that list?

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online

In our company they have different group for email address and when they gave access to the SharePoint lists, they have two different permission for the same person. Which permission would be the final on? the most access or limited one?

I feel it would be the least access but I dont see that as a result

Answer (score 0):

You could grant full control permission for group containing admin users, and grant read permission for group containing normal users.

Answer (score 0):

Seems Like the higher permission will be apply even though you give that user limited access in another group in the same list/site or etc.